# Android: Table Row Insert Error. Column does not exist?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, insert

So previously I implemented a DB with a table that had 2 columns. I changed my mind and added one more column to the table and tried inserting the new value and I faced this problem even though I correctly (I believe) added all the right column declarations in the classes mentioned below.

**TableData Class that contains the column names and data:**

```
public class ImageTableData {

    public ImageTableData()
    {

    }
    public static abstract class ImagesTableData implements BaseColumns
    {
        public static final String ImageID = "imid";
        public static final String PID = "pid";
        public static final String URL = "url";
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jezza_db";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "product_pics";
    }
}
```

**And my Query in the DatabaseOperations class:**

```
public String CREATE_IMAGE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + ImagesTableData.TABLE_NAME + " (" + ImagesTableData.ImageID + " VARCHAR, " + ImagesTableData.PID + " VARCHAR, " + ImagesTableData.URL + " VARCHAR);";
```

**And my create query execution:**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_IMAGE_QUERY);
        }
```

I believe those are the two declarations. However I started getting THIS error when I added a new column "ImageID". It worked well before when it had only 2 columns.

```
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteLog(21777): (1) table product_pics has no column named imid
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777): Error inserting pid=77153628 imid=imablack3jpg url=http://storage.googleapis.com/bucketjezza/black3.jpg
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table product_pics has no column named imid (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO product_pics(pid,imid,url) VALUES (?,?,?)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1121)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:694)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1589)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1461)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at function.DBOps.insertImages(DBOps.java:138)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at activity.classes.HomeActivity.commitToDatabase(HomeActivity.java:287)
    12-22 14:13:25.345: E/SQLiteDatabase(21777):    at activity.classes.HomeActivity$2.onSuccess(HomeActivity.java:235)
```

**And my SELECT query crashed as well, returning this error:**

```
12-22 14:13:25.355: E/SQLiteLog(21777): (1) no such column: ImageID
12-22 14:13:25.355: E/DB ERROR(21777): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ImageID (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT ImageID FROM product_pics WHERE ImageID=imaimablack3jpg
```

My SELECT Query and code block:

```
public boolean isImageAdded(DBOps dop, String id)
    {
        try
        {
            String idmod = "ima" + id;
            boolean isAdded = false;
            Log.d("URL Recieved: ", id);
            SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT ImageID FROM "+ ImagesTableData.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE ImageID="+idmod; 
            Cursor cursor = SQ.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
            Log.d("Cursor Count : ", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
            {
                cursor.close();
                isAdded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cursor.close();
                isAdded = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", ex.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Why is this happening? I have added the new column correctly havent I? Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your query

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT imid FROM "+ ImagesTableData.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE imid ='"+idmod+"'";
```

There is no Column Name `ImageID` available in your Table. You defined `ImageID=imid`.

OR another way

```
 String sqlQuery = "SELECT "+ ImagesTableData.ImageID +" FROM "+ ImagesTableData.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE "+ ImagesTableData.ImageID + " = '"+idmod+"'";
```

Comment: This solved that issue but now the application is referring to an image id as a column o.O The error I get now says: 
"(1) no such column: ima10847010102045632116556882008366137njpg
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ima10847010102045632116556882008366137njpg (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT imid FROM product_pics WHERE imid=ima10847010102045632116556882008366137njpg". Obviously there's no column like that :/ Thats an image id

Comment: @BenildusRatnayake Then pass the ImageID. whatever it is.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm passing sir. 
String sqlQuery = "SELECT " + ImagesTableData.ImageID + " FROM "+ ImagesTableData.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE imid="+id; 
id is the image id. But the error says it's a column?

Comment: @BenildusRatnayake Why you added `ima` and `jpg` in `id`. Directly check with id value

Comment: I consider that long value as the ID sir. my problem is that error I posted in the comments. What do you think?

Comment: @BenildusRatnayake also pass `imid` value in `single quote(')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67449/discussion-between-m-d-and-benildus-ratnayake).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to retrieve the non existing field `ImageID`:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT ImageID FROM "+  ...
```

Instead, you have a field called `imid`, as defined here:

```
public static final String ImageID = "imid";
```

So, the correct query is:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT imid FROM "+  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the application and install again then your problem will be solved.

Because whenever the database file is not there in application directory then only the `onCreate()` method of database helper class will be called. if our application directory is having database file is available it wont call `onCreate()` method of database helper class.if you reinstalled the application without uninstalling the database file will not be deleted. so `onCreate()` of database helper class will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Change you sql query from

```
"SELECT ImageID FROM "+ ImagesTableData.TABLE_NAME
```

to

```
"SELECT " + ImagesTableData.ImageID + " FROM "+ ImagesTableData.TABLE_NAME
```